# How do I read my facebook post feed through the Graph Explorer?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I created a test app for facebook that is supposed to read the user's profile to get their posts.

Under App Details -> App Center Listed Platforms I clicked on the "Configure App Center Permissions" button, and added "read_stream" and "user_posts" permissions for the app.

I then go into Tools & Support -> Access Token Tool and grant myself a session token.

I then go into Tools & Support -> Graph API Explorer, paste in the session token, and access the following URL: `me/feed`, but get the following debug error:

`The field 'feed' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants either the 'user_posts' or 'read_stream' permission.`

Except, I have no place to do that. I went into my public Facebook profile to adjust the app settings, but there is no setting to grant feed read permissions.

I clicked on the "Debug" button next to the access token in the developer tools, and it showed the scopes as "user_friends, public_profile" instead of the full permission scopes the app wants.

I'm able to create test users and log them in with the right permissions, but the problem is that test users have no feeds or data, and I don't want to manually create a bunch of fake feed data.

How do I get my OWN FEED from my OWN APP during testing?

Comment: have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

During the authorization process you have to indicate which permissions are necessary for your app. By default, only the "public profile permission" is allowed, but the rest must be added in the argument scope.

Example: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?**scope=user_posts**&redirect_uri=http://localhost/login&client_id=XXXXXXXXX&response_type=code

You can also add more permissions: "scope=user_posts user_location user_games_activity".

[Facebook Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_events).

Best regards,
Gonzalo.